# How to eliminate duplicate filename in hadoop mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop

I want to eliminate duplicate filenames in my output of the hadoop mapreduce inverted index program. For example, the output is like - *things : doc1,doc1,doc1,doc2* but I want it to be like 
*things : doc1,doc2*

Answer (score 1):

Well you want to remove duplicates which were mapped, i.e. you want to **reduce** the intermediate value list to an output list with no duplicates. My best bet would be to simply convert the `Iterator<Text>` in the `reduce()` method to a java `Set` and iterate over it changing:

```
while (values.hasNext()) {
    if (!first)
    toReturn.append(", ") ;
    first = false;
    toReturn.append(values.next().toString());
}
```

To something like:

```
Set<Text> valueSet = new HashSet<Text>();
while (values.hasNext()) {
    valueSet.add(values.next());
}

for(Text value : valueSet) {
    if(!first) {
        toReturn.append(", ");
    }
    first = false;
    toReturn.append(value.toString());
}
```

Unfortunately I do not know of any better (more concise) way of converting an Iterator to a Set.

This should have a smaller time complexity than orange's solution but a higher memory consumption.

@Edit: a bit shorter:

```
Set<Text> valueSet = new HashSet<Text>();
while (values.hasNext()) {
    Text next = values.next();
    if(!valueSet.contains(next)) {
        if(!first) {
            toReturn.append(", ");
        }
        first = false;
        toReturn.append(value.toString());
        valueSet.add(next);
    }
}
```

Contains should be (just like add) constant time so it should be O(n) now.

Comment: Your solution is what I was suggesting towards the end of my answer, and is the best solution. Actually, our space complexity is the same because I have to buffer the results into the StringBuffer before writing them out.

Comment: yup but I also have that StringBuilder (because that is what we actually return) but I also have the Set which stores unique results. Ah I guess we could also optimize it by appending it all in the "while" look and adding a simple if/else check. The question is what would be faster: an extra if in every step of the while loop or the second for loop.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter in the grand scheme of Hadoop things :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this with the minimal amount of code change, just add an if-statement that checks to see if the thing you are about to append is already in `toReturn`:

```
if (!first)
    toReturn.append(", ") ;
first = false;
toReturn.append(values.next().toString());
```

gets changed to

```
String v = values.next().toString()
if (toReturn.indexOf(v) == -1) {  // indexOf returns -1 if it is not there
    if (!first) {
        toReturn.append(", ") ;
    }
    toReturn.append(v);
    first = false
}
```

---

The above solution is a bit slow because it has to traverse the entire string every time to see if that string is there. Likely the best way to do this is to use a `HashSet` to collect the items, then combining the values in the `HashSet` into a final output string.